# Excel Solver: Maximizing the length of time under multi-period contraints

Tags: excel, math, numerical-methods, solver

I've been trying to figure out, using excel solver, how to set up my spreadsheet to solve a more complex version of this problem. The problem is as follows: I have 3 squares (5 units in length). Each one has a different starting position on an x-y axis. There are 6 rounds to the game. At the end of each round the squares drift at a constant rate but each square drifts at a different rate. The Goal is to pick a point(doesn't have to be unique) that stays the longest(number of rounds) in any given rectangle.

The center points for each rectangle in any given round is below:

```
Rectangle 1 Rectangle 2     Rectangle 3     
Round   x-axis  y-axis  x-axis  y-axis  x-axis  y-axis  
0       5       15  2.5 17.5    7.5 12.5  
1   5.7 14.3    3   17  8.4 11.6  
2   6.4 13.6    3.5 16.5    9.3 10.7  
3   7.1 12.9    4   16  10.2    9.8  
4   7.8 12.2    4.5 15.5    11.1    8.9  
5   8.5 11.5    5   15  12  8  
6   9.2 10.8    5.5 14.5    12.9    7.1
```

Any idea how I can set this up and solve it? Thanks.

Comment: This problem doesn't lend itself well to using the solver.  The objective function changes in steps, so the solver can't look at local variation to determine how to adjust.  I think you probably could create an alternate version of the problem that would provide a solution - switch to continuous rather than stepped movement - but in this case the answer is simply the corner pointing in the direction that the square is moving.

Comment: Depending on what the more complex version looks like, you'll probably either want to either drop the stepped motion and make this a calculus problem or calculate the overlap of the area covered from step to step, and count for how many successive it is non-zero.

Comment: If you are still interested in this problem, let me know and I will post a solution.